# Popen with PIPE blocks called process, when it's output large enough, how to unblock it?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to start subprocess, which can just exit, printing something to console, or never exits (became a web server e.g.).

So in my runner I'd like to check is process still running or already exits, and do it in completely unblocking manner, so if it exits, I'd like to capture the output.

So it looks like this

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

with Popen(
        [
            sys.executable,
            r"...\stub1.py"
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        encoding="utf-8",
) as proc:
    while True:
        ret = proc.poll()
        print(ret)
        if ret is not None: break
        sleep(1)
```

where `stub1.py` is just

```
print("foo"*100)
```

So it works fine while output of subprocess is relatively small.

```
None
0
```

But with larger output called process is blocked (on writing to filled pipe as I understand) and never exits, so `poll()` always returns `None`.

So how to unblock called process, flushing pipe in unblocking manner?

I see I can pass real file descriptors for stdout/stderr, but is it possible with PIPEs?

Comment: Why not use communicate() or read from `proc.stdout` instead of waiting for the process to terminate? Once it terminates, it will close the pipe. Another option would be to use [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) to check if the output is available.

Comment: It seems to get blocked once the output reaches over 65536 bytes, which seems to be some kind of buffering issue

Comment: If you don't intend to ever read the process's output, then why send it to a pipe (that has no way of discarding data without actually reading it)?  Send it to `open(os.devnull, 'w')` instead.

Comment: If you want your child to be able to outlive the parent, general good practice is _not_ to communicate over stdout or stderr at all in the first place. Look at how the `sd_notify` protocol works (as used by systemd services having `Type=notify`), passing the name of a pipe that the child is responsible for reporting status to, but can also just ignore if it stops being available.

Comment: It's also a done thing (though one I disapprove of) to have the child stay in the foreground long enough to check whether it's able to do its startup and report any errors, but fork again and self-detach after successfully going into long-lived server mode; that's what systemd calls `Type=forking`.

Comment: In general, though, if you don't want the child to block, then _always continuously be reading from the other side of its pipelines_. This is the kind of thing one spawns a thread to do. It doesn't matter much how large the pipe buffer is if you do the responsible thing and empty it.

Comment: *always continuously be reading from the other side of its pipelines* but how to do it in non-blocking manner? I don't know does callee write even something to pipe, I can not use communicate because it will block caller process, nither read from pipe because it will block also if no data is produced.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently subprocess pipes have a size limit of 65536, which you can change simply by adding a `pipesize` argument to your `Popen`. A reasonable maximum value (for Linux, not sure about other OS) is 1024KB (`1024*1024=1048576` bytes). You can apply this modification to your code like this:

```py
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

with Popen(
        [
            sys.executable,
            r"...\stub1.py"
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        encoding="utf-8",
        pipesize=1024*1024
) as proc:
    while True:
        ret = proc.poll()
        print(ret)
        if ret is not None: break
        sleep(1)
```

I tested this with a sample program and it works just fine.

If 1024 KB still is not enough, you could just use `os.set_blocking()` on the Popen's stdout like this:

```py
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

with Popen(
        [
            sys.executable,
            r"...\stub1.py"
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        encoding="utf-8",
        pipesize=1024*1024
) as proc:
     os.set_blocking(proc.stdout.fileno(),os.O_NONBLOCK)
     while True:
         output = proc.stdout.read()
         if output:
            break
         # do stuff
```

This, however, works only on Linux, so if you are using Windows, you might want to check something like `threading` if the program outputs more than 1024KB
Read more: https://bugs.python.org/issue41586 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.set_blocking

Comment: This is all true, but it's not obvious to me that it answers the question / solves the problem. You're moving the failure point around, but not changing whether there'll eventually be a failure.